# How do I store a Value from a cell into a Variable

Tags: vba

So, I'm writing a program to calculate my students grades, and it seems like I am not storing the values in variables I need to work with. I keep getting a `Type Error Message` when run the code.

Here's the code below. Do you have any suggestions?

```vb
Public Sub FinalGrade()

    Dim essay1 As Double
    Dim essay2 As Integer
    Dim essay3 As Integer
    Dim midterm As Integer
    Dim final As Integer
    Dim in_class As Integer
    Dim essay_avg As Integer
    Dim midterm_avg As Integer
    Dim final_avg As Integer
    Dim in_class_avg As Integer

    Dim x As Integer

    Do While x <> ""
        For x = 2 To 100
            essay1 = Cells(x, c).Value
            essay2 = Cells(x, d).Value
            essay3 = Cells(x, e).Value
            midterm = Cells(x, f).Value
            final_essay = Cells(x, g).Value
            in_class = Cells(x, h).Value


            essay_avg = ((essay1 + essay2 + essay3) / 3) * 0.3
            midterm_avg = midterm * 0.15
            final_avg = final * 0.15
            in_class_avg = in_class * 0.3

            Cells(x, j).Value = essay_avg + midterm_avg + final_avg + in_class_avg + 10
        Next x
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: And on which line do you get the error?

Comment: Note, you probably want to just use `Double` - using `Integer` will silently drop any decimal places.

Comment: The `Do While` loop is redundant.

Comment: I get the error on this line: essay1 = Cells(x, c).Value

Comment: Put the column letters in quotation. Otherwise it is a variable that is undeclared

Answer (score -1):

try this Convert.ToDouble(Cells(x, c).Value)

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble` is VB.NET, which is a completely different language. In VBA the function is `CDbl`